# Como faço para dividir uma barra de gráfico em "%" no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: Tabelas de Motivos de Atraso]

Bom dia,
Possuo um gráfico que representa uma quantidade total de motivos de atraso de 4 empresas
num total.
Alguém sabe como faço para dividir as barras, para representar o quanto cada empresa representa num total dos atrasos?
Sendo necessário envio o arquivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, bom dia! Primeiro você precisa converter sua tabela em porcentagem. Dividi os valores (da primeira coluna, por exemplo: 330, 669, 3 e 0) pelo total (Ex: 330/1002) e utilizei o botão de porcentagem para formatá-lo da forma correta. Então, no primeiro exemplo teríamos as porcentagens de 33%, 67%, 0,3% e 0% +-
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
A partir dessas porcentagens, criei o gráfico, utilizando a opção colunas > colunas empilhadas, que transforma cada coluna da tua tabela numa coluna do gráfico, separando os motivos por colunas e as empresas por cores, mantendo a porcentagem como eixo vertical. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois você só precisa formatar para aparecer (ou não) os 0% etc.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Opa, Obrigado!!
Consegui evoluir aqui no trabalho. Valeu cara.